# How to Escape Double Quotes from Ruby Page Object text

Tags: ruby, text, escaping, double-quotes, page-object-gem

In using the Page Object gem, I'm trying to pull text from a page to verify error messages. One of these error messages contains double-quotes, but when the page object pulls the text from the page, it pulls some other characters.

```
expected ["Please select a category other than the Default â?oEMSâ?? before saving."] 
to include "Please select a category other than the Default \"EMS\" before saving." 
(RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
```

I'm not quite sure how to escape these - I'm not sure where I could use Regexs and be able to escape these odd characters.

Comment: Can you post the code that generates this error message? How are you using the page-object gem? Also, it seems there is some way of changing the encoding using the gem, have you tried anything along those lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly you are over complicating your validation.

I would recommend simplifying what you are trying to do, start by asking yourself: Is the part in quotes a critical part of your validation?

If it is, isolate it by doing a String.contains("EMS")

If it is not, then you are probably doing too much work, only check for exactly what you need in validation:

String.beginsWith("Please select a category other than the Default")

With respect to the actual issue you are having, on a technical level you have an encoding issue. Encode your result string with utf-8 before you pass it to your validation and you will be fine.

Good luck

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I do need the part in quotes as part of the validation as there are multiple similar error messages and I need to make sure that I'm getting the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty likely that somewhere along the line encoded the string improperly. (A tipoff is the accented characters followed by `?`.) It seems pretty likely that the quotes were converted to "smart quotes" somewhere. [This table](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html) compares Window-1252 to UTF-8:

```
Code Point      Characters          UTF-8 Bytes
Unicode Windows
        1252    Expected    Actual
------  ----    -           ---     ----------- 
U+201C  0x93    “           â€œ     %E2 %80 %9C
U+201D  0x94    ”           â€      %E2 %80 %9D
```

What you'll want to do is spot check various places in the code to find the first place the string is encoded in something other than UTF-8:

```
puts error_str.encoding
```

(For clarity, `error_str` is the variable that holds the string you are testing. I'm using `puts`, but you might want have another way to log diagnostic messages.)

Once you find the string that's not encoded UTF-8, you can convert it:

```
error_str.encode('UTF-8')
```

Or, if the string is hardcoded somewhere, just replace the string.

For more debugging advice, see: [3 Steps to Fix Encoding Problems in Ruby](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-steps-to-fix-encoding-problems-in-ruby/) and [How to Get From Theyâ€™re to They’re](http://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-to-get-from-theyre-to-theyre/).